# Why does Entity Framework try to SELECT all columns even though I have specified only two?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've inherited an ASP MVC project that uses Entity Framework 6.1.3 to interact with a Dynamics CRM 2011 SQL database.

I'm using this query to try and get all active accounts that have an account number and I'm selecting only two columns into an anonymous type:

```
var results = context.Accounts
              .Where(a => (a.AccountNumber != null) 
                       && (a.StateCode == (int)AccountState.Active))
              .Select(a => new 
              { 
                  a.AccountId, 
                  a.AccountNumber 
              });
```

(`context` is the `DbContext`, `Accounts` is a `DbSet<Account>`, `Account` has ALL fields defined including ones deleted since the project was created. These were generated by EF.)

When executing the query I get the following exception:

> Invalid column name "Opportunity_1", "Opportunity_2", ... , "Opportunity_7"

All of the columns mentioned are the ones that have been removed from the database since this project was created.

The error occurs because the SQL query that EF runs actually looks like this:

```
SELECT     
    [Extent1].[StateCode] AS [StateCode],     
    [Extent1].[AccountId] AS [AccountId],     
    [Extent1].[AccountNumber] AS [AccountNumber]   

FROM (SELECT     
        [Account].[AccountId] AS [AccountId],     
        [Account].[AccountNumber] AS [AccountNumber],     
        ...
        !! EVERY SINGLE COLUMN !!
        ...
        [Account].[Opportunity_1] AS [Opportunity_1], // These have been deleted
        [Account].[Opportunity_2] AS [Opportunity_2]  // from the database

      FROM [dbo].[Account] AS [Account]) AS [Extent1] 

 WHERE ([Extent1].[AccountNumber] IS NOT NULL) AND (0 = [Extent1].[StateCode])
```

I didn't expect it to try and select every single column, obviously since fields have been deleted from the database but not the model I get the error.

I've read several posts that indicate that my query looks correct and that it should only select the 3 required columns and ignore the rest: 
[one](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/09/select-specific-columns-entity-framework-query/) / [two](https://colinmackay.scot/2011/07/31/getting-just-the-columns-you-want-from-entity-framework/) / [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328136/select-certain-fields-from-dbsett)

I want to avoid having to regenerate the whole schema/model/whatever from the database or I'd find myself doing this every time I made a change to the database.

**Is it possible to select only these 2 columns from the database and ignore all others or is this just how EF works and I'll have the update the model and redeploy the project each time?**

---

Here is the entire `DbContext` model:

```
namespace AccountMarker.Models
{
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class CRMEntities : DbContext
    {
        public CRMEntities()
            : base("name=CRMEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to LINQ2Entities, If you want to get more accurate query, write a stored procedure and map it with entity framework.

Comment: add AsQueryable() in this query and check the sql. I don't think so that the SQL you are showing is correct.

Comment: what sql is generated if you select Accounts instead of anonymous?

Comment: @Valkyriee If I can help it I want to avoid modifying the database, it's a long and drawn out change process to do so. I'll bear this in mind as n option though.

Comment: @AnkushJain Adding `AsQueryable` doesn't change anything. The SQL might not be copy/paste correct as I had to remove 40k+ characters from it, but it is an accurate representation.

Comment: @Crowcoder The exact same SQL is generated whether I select into an anonymous object or my early bound class.

Comment: Does the order of the `Where` and `Select` clauses change anything?

Comment: Thats unfortunate, but the models should stay in sync with the db schema. Thats why code first migrations are now popular, to take away some of that pain.

Comment: @InBetween Unfortunately it's exactly the same

Comment: @Crowcoder Yeah, I figured that they ideally stay in sync, it just seems horribly inefficient to select all columns every time you query an entity. Sounds like there should be a way around it, unless this is a horrible oversight.

Comment: This is odd, do you have any additional entity config you're not showing? Maybe your `OnModelCreating` method does something in the context? Which version of Entity Framework are you using?

Comment: You could add a [NotMapped] attribute to properties in the model that don't have a corresponding column anymore. This way EF will ignore them.

Comment: @DavidG I've added the CRMEntities model, OnModelCreating is the default which was auto generated. I'm not aware of any additional entity config, but I inherited this project so I could be missing something. Any pointers on what you were thinking of?

Comment: @Equalsk Yes, looks like your entity config is OK. Which version of EF is it using?

Comment: @CiprianLipan That's definitely my plan B. Ideally I still want to understand why this doesn't work as I'm convinced it should.

Comment: @DavidG Specifically version 6.1.3.

Comment: Hmm, curiouser and curiouser! Your query above isn't actually materialised, you're not doing anything odd with it later on?

Comment: @DavidG It materializes on the line after when I access the results in a `for` loop. `foreach(var account in results) { // Do something with account };` This is the line which throws the error when that SQL statement is run. The method is pretty rudimentary and just checks if the account is within another List<T>.

Comment: And I assume if you add `ToList()` on the end of your query, it throws the exception there instead?

Comment: @DavidG Indeed it does. Don't have the same issue if I use CRMs own proprietary data context from the SDK with the exact same LINQ query (which is another potential fix but requires changing a load of stuff).

Comment: I admit I'm quite confused now, there's no reason for this to happen at all. The SQL query should be built logically by the expression tree you have created, and there is nothing here to suggest that. So unless you have something really odd in your entity or are using an unusual provider, I'm stumped :)

Comment: @DavidG Hehe, no problem. Me too. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: did you get error while building or runtime?

Comment: @user7417866 Runtime as soon as the query is executed

Comment: see my answer, preferably user first method, I always encounter same problem with my team members. :) hope it helps :)

Comment: Usually EF does not generate such SQLs for simple queries like this (at least latest EF6.1.3). What EF version are you on?

Comment: @IvanStoev I know, puzzling isn't it. I'm on 6.1.3. I assume my predecessor did something weird when setting this up but I can't see it.

Comment: Indeed. It's interesting as soon as you are not the one who really needs to solve it :) Probably the best is to just update the model to be in sync and move on.

Comment: @IvanStoev I'm just a stickler for understanding *why* something was broken, makes me uneasy to just fix it and move on. That said, I do agree, tempted to just update the model and call it even. Tired of looking at it.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using an existing database *and* handling via Database First, with EDMX. Doing it that way, there is no choice but to regenerate all the entities and EDMX from the database again when the database changes. However, if you switch to Code First (which can be used with existing databases, despite the name), then all you need to do is alter your entity to match your DB schema and you're done. See for more info: http://cpratt.co/entity-framework-code-first-with-existing-database/

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thanks, that sounds more like what I want, I'll take a look at that. Do you know if it's possible to have the entity defined with only key fields such as id and name where the database will have some 400 fields? I ideally don't want to have to maintain a 1 to 1 map like that as I don't want to have to redeploy this every time the database changes.

Comment: Yes. That should work. You'll need to test it of course, but I know if you do something like remove a property, but don't migrate the database afterwards, it doesn't cause errors, so this should be roughly the same thing on a grander scale.

Comment: Which Dynamics CRM query provider do you have? I wonder if it supports projections well, although it seems *very* strange not to.

Comment: @GertArnold To query the database it's just EF 6.1.3 connected directly to SQL server, it's some degrees of magnitude faster to query this rather than the CRM endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create entities and delete the specific columns which where mapped earlier, EF will took the reference for same and will try to find the columns based on entities and not on query you made.

Quick solution, remove the entity of table build project and add it again into emdx model and rebuilt again.

alternatively remove all the columns form the dbcontext that are deleted.

Comment: Ultimately this is what I ended up doing to solve the issue, I rebuilt the model. Would have liked to find out what was wrong but it was wasting too much time.

Comment: yes, this was the common problem with my team and I took lots of effort to resolve that time.

Answer (score 0):

Use not mapped attribute on model's fields that you don't need in BD