# EF6 count query of table vs view

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm finding that EF6 is generating different SQL when I need to get a count from a table vs a view.

Let's assume I have a table in SQL Server called Students.  Assume there's a view that filters that table; we'll call it CurrentStudents.

When I use EF6 to get the count of the table, the query that EF creates is quite different from what it generates when I query the view count.  I'm trying to understand why it does it differently.

I have example code below.

Looking at the table count code, we have:

```
context.Students.Where(x => x.Status == 1).Count()
```

That generates the EF query:

```
SELECT [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM (SELECT
COUNT(1) AS [A1]
FROM [STUDENTS] AS [Extent1]
WHERE 1 = [Extent1].STATUS)
AS [GroupBy1]
```

EF generates the Count SQL and wraps it in another SELECT.  No problem with that.

Now contrast to just changing the code to get the view count:

```
context.CurrentStudents.Where(x => x.Status == 1).Count()
```

Generated view query:

```
SELECT [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM (SELECT
COUNT(1) AS [A1]
FROM (SELECT [STUDENTS].[ID] as [ID],
[STUDENTS].[STATUS] AS [STATUS],
[STUDENTS].[FIRSTNAME] AS [FIRSTNAME],
[STUDENTS].[LASTNAME] AS [LASTNAME],
[STUDENTS].[AGE] AS [AGE],
[STUDENTS].[MAJOR] AS [MAJOR],
[STUDENTS].[MINOR] AS [MINOR],
[STUDENTS].[DORM] AS [DORM],
[STUDENTS].[GRADDATE] AS [GRADDATE]
FROM [CURRENTSTUDENTS] AS [CURRENTSTUDENTS])
) AS [Extent1]
WHERE 1 = [Extent1].STATUS)
AS [GroupBy1]
```

The EF query in this case has added another nested SELECT, which is selecting every column that is available in the view.  I'm not sure why EF has decided to add that extra level of verbosity just because a view is the count source.  Just wondering if anyone has a better understanding of what's going on behind the scenes here.

Comment: I am not observing this /w EF6 & SQL Server, whether I have an entity mapped to a table or a view I am getting the same SQL. How is your CurrentStudents entity mapped to the view, as well as the underlying view definition?

Comment: It's a basic "Update model from database".  All the mapping is auto-generated by EF.  Nothing more.  Seems pretty similar to this issue:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42670128/why-does-entity-framework-try-to-select-all-columns-even-though-i-have-specified
I've tried various methods to generate queries; Linq, Entity SQL, JOINs, subqueries.  Always the same full SELECT.

Comment: Can you add the entity definition and any configuration classes or modelBuilder statements for that class? Where I have pointed entities at views it does use the view name in the resulting SELECT, so I'm curious what might cause that behavior to differ.

Comment: The definitions look good and I can use them without issue.  All of the entity names match the views as expected.  It's just the underlying SQL that's being generated for the view fetches that isn't what I'd call optimal, unlike the table fetches.  One thing that I noticed is a 6002 warning that there's no PK for the views so EF is inferring one itself and making the view read-only.  That should be fine,  but it was using a large collection of columns for a PK.  I reset that to a logical PK value using a single column, even though I'm not updating.  Still, the generated query SQL is the same.

Comment: In order to help, we need a minimal reproducible scenario. When I create a view and point an EF entity at it, I get an SQL statement that refers to the view without referencing the individual table columns that make up the view. Something particular to your implementation must be the source of that, without seeing that I don't think anyone can help.